Tabulator download xlsx with created date
How can I add created date to Excel file generated and downloaded using Tabulator?
So far I have this
jobsTable.download('xlsx', `${excelFriendlyName}.xlsx`, {
  documentProcessing(workbook) {
   
    workbook.Props = {
      CreatedDate: new Date(),
    };
  
    return workbook;
  },
});

which gives me

but I have no idea how to append it to the bottom of the Excel document

Add the date value to a given row/column in your workbook. Right now you're just adding it as metadata to the file itself
